# What are the technical differences between these two versions of the NCC-1701?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-2009, star-trek-reboot

What are the major technical differences between the Enterprise NCC-1701 (TOS) and NCC-1701 (Abrams)? I don't recall TOS engineering looking like a sterile brewery or having a large transparent water pipe with those ridiculous blender blades. Did they both [have balls](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/94273/54605)? Are there technical manuals for both ships?

I'm not looking for an exhaustive list as it would likely be too broad. I just want major differences to try and determine if Abrams' NCC-1701 is more advanced than TOS' NCC-1701 and by how much. I prefer any in-universe answers but will accept out-of-universe explanations.

Comment: http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/new_enterprise_comment.htm might give you a start, http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org is - in general - a good site for that kind of question....